# Singletons and factories with multiple libraries in C++

Tags: c++, singleton, shared-libraries, factory-pattern, object-construction

I've been reading and searching the web for a while now but haven't found a nice solution. Here's what I want to do:

I am writing a library that defines an abstract base class - lets call it **IFoo**.

```
class IFoo {
    public:
        virtual void doSomething() = 0;
        virtual ~IFoo() {}
};
```

The library also defines a couple of implementations for that - lets call them **FooLibOne** and **FooLibTwo**.

In order to encapsulate the creation process and decide which concrete implementation is used depending on some runtime paramter, I use a factory **FooFactory** that maps std::string to factory methods (in my case boost::function, but that should not be the point here). It also allows new factory methods to be registered. It looks something like this:

```
class FooFactory {
    public:
         typedef boost::function<IFoo* ()> CreatorFunction;

         IFoo* create(std::string name);
         void registerCreator(std::string name, CreatorFunction f);

    private:
         std::map<std::string, CreatorFunction> mapping_;
};
```

For now, I added the implementations provided (FooLibOne, FooLibTwo) by the library directly in the constructor of **FooFactory** - thus they are always available. Some of the library code uses the FooFactory to initialize certain objects etc. I have refrained from using the Singleton pattern for the factories so far since tee pattern is debated often enough and I wasn't sure, how different implementations of the Singleton pattern would work in combination with possibly multiple shared libraries etc.

However, passing around the factories can be a little cumbersome and I still think, this is one of the occassions the Singleton pattern could be of good use. Especially if I consider, that the users of the library should be able to add more implementations of **IFoo** which should also be accessible for the (already existing) library code. Of course, Dependency Injection - meaning I pass an instance of a factory through the constructor - could do the trick (and does it for now). But this approach kind of fails if I want to be even more flexible and introduce a second layer of dynamic object creation. Meaning: I want to dynamicly create objects (see above) within dynamically created objects (say implementations of an abstract base class **IBar** - **BarOne** and **BarTwo** - again via a factory **BarFactory**).

Lets say **BarOne** requires an **IFoo** object but **BarTwo** doesn't. I still have to provide the **FooFactory** to the **BarFactory** in any case, since one of the **IBar** implementations *might* need it. Having globally accessible factories would mitigate this problem and I wouldn't be forced to forsee, which factories may be needed by implementations of a specific interface. In addition I could register the creation methods directly in the source file of the implementations.

```
FooFactory::Instance().registerCreator("new_creator", boost::bind(...));
```

Since I think it is a good idea, what would be the right way to implement it? I was going for a templated approach like the **SingletonHolder** from *Modern C++ Design* (see also [Loki](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/) library) to wrap the factories. However, I'd rather implement it as a Meyer's Singleton instead. But I still think there will be issues with shared libraries. The solution should work with GCC (and preferably MSVC). I'm also open for other ideas from a design point of view but please avoid the common "Singletons are evil"-rants. ;-)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Singletons are evil.  ;-)  I know you don't want to hear this, but at least now people who want to say it can just vote for this comment!

Comment: @JohnZwinck: Thanks for saving keystrokes!

Comment: "second layer of dynamic object creation" when you happen to have a `TrucBiduleFactoryFactory`, your design sucks.

Comment: You're most probably right. However, that's not what I meant. Let's say I have a factory that creates different (generic) cars. Few of them are emergency vehicles and thus need a siren (which is dynamically created with a siren factory as well, since there are several kinds of sirens). I don't think it is a good idea to always "inject" the SirenFactory into the CarFactory just because a few of the cars need a siren. A global SirenFactory would be accessible if needed and ignored otherwise.

Comment: @rocktale As you point out, the CarFactory does not need to know about the SirenFactory, but your PoliceCarCreator and AmbulanceCreator would both need to know about the SirenFactory.   Are your 'creators' implemented as standalone functions or as Function Objects?   Personally I would use Function objects and ensure that vehicles which need sirens are created by function objects which know about the SirenFactory - this way the CarFactory can remain blissfully unaware about any other factories or vehicle-specific dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, 76 lines of code speak more than a few words - (using C++11 version of these features instead of the boost ones, but they're pretty much the same anyway)

I would put the definition of the *factory(ies)* and the definition of the *creators* in the same (or nearby) scope, so that each of the creators can "see" any of their dependent factories - avoiding the need to pass factories around too much, and avoiding singletons

Cars & Sirens:

```
class ISiren {};
class Siren : public ISiren 
{
public:
    Siren() { std::cout << "Siren Created" << std::endl; }
};

class ICar{};
class EstateCar : public ICar 
{
public:
    EstateCar() { std::cout << "EstateCar created" << std::endl;}
};
class PoliceCar : public ICar 
{
    std::shared_ptr<ISiren> siren;
public:
    PoliceCar( std::shared_ptr<ISiren> siren)
        : siren( siren ) 
    {
        std::cout << "PoliceCar created" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Factories:

```
typedef std::function< std::shared_ptr<ICar> () > CreatorType;

class CarFactory
{
    std::map<std::string, CreatorType> creators;
public:
    void AddFactory( std::string type, CreatorType func )
    {
        creators.insert( std::make_pair(type, func) );
    }

    std::shared_ptr<ICar> CreateCar( std::string type )
    {
        CreatorType& create( creators[type] );
        return create();
    }
};

class SirenFactory
{
public: // Simple factory creating 1 siren type just for brevity
    std::shared_ptr<ISiren> CreateSiren() { return std::make_shared<Siren>(); }
};
```

"Factory Root" (main function, wherever factories are defined) :

```
int main()
{
    CarFactory car_factory; // Car factory unaware of Siren factory
    SirenFactory siren_factory;

    auto EstateCarLambda = []() { 
        return std::make_shared<EstateCar>(); 
    }; // Estate car lambda knows nothing of the Siren Factory

    auto PoliceCarLambda = [&siren_factory]() {
        return std::make_shared<PoliceCar>( siren_factory.CreateSiren() );
    };  // Police car creation lambda using the Siren Factory

    car_factory.AddFactory( "EstateCar", EstateCarLambda );

    car_factory.AddFactory( "PoliceCar", PoliceCarLambda );

    std::shared_ptr<ICar> car1 = car_factory.CreateCar( "EstateCar" );
    std::shared_ptr<ICar> car2 = car_factory.CreateCar( "PoliceCar" );
}
```